# Aligning content inside a div and changing background color

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

first time bootstrap user here and I am helping some more experienced users can answer a couple questions I have.

reference site: http://ps11.pstcc.edu/~c2230a11/lab4/jraudi

First, I have created one giant container where my nav bar and carousal are positioned. Under my carousal I have created an additional container in 4 x 4 x 4 rows to equal the required 12. I have centered the pictures within these rows, unfortunately when I enter text I am unable to align the text within the boundaries of the picture. I've tried using  but that doesn't work as well as I wanted. So, I figured I would ask if their is an alternative method.

```
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4">
      <img class="center-block" src="images/newveh.png" alt="Generic placeholder image" width="280" height="175">
      <h3><b>New Vehicles</b></h3>
      <p>Jr Audi has the latest Audi models available.</p>
      <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button">&raquo; View New Inventory</a></p>
    </div><!-- /.col-lg-4 -->
    <div class="col-lg-4">
      <img class="center-block" src="images/certpreowned.png" alt="Generic placeholder image" width="280" height="175">
      <h3><b>Certified Pre-Owned Vehicles</b></h3>
      <p>Audi Certified Pre-Owned inspection is the industry's most rigorous.</p>
      <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button">&raquo; View Certified pre-owned Vehicles</a>
  &raquo;</p>
    </div><!-- /.col-lg-4 -->
    <div class="col-lg-4">
      <img class="center-block" src="images/specialoffers.png" alt="Generic placeholder image" width="280" height="175">
      <h3><b>Special Offers</h3></b>
      <p>If you are considering a new Audi vehicle, now is the perfect opportunity.</p>
      <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button">&raquo; View Incentives</a></p>
    </div><!-- /.col-lg-4 -->
  </div><!-- /.row -->
```

Also, in regards to using background colors. I want to change the background color outside of my primary container, so everything to the far left or right. I've attempted to change the background color before and managed to change everything. How do I change only the background color outside of my main container?

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 Parts to this question:

1) Changing the background colour, you will need to set "background-color" on the Body, as well as setting a white (or any desired colour) on the container div. The div is transparent by default, so when you are updating the colour, it is visible through the transparent div.

2) Aligning the text should be as simple as using the CSS "text-align: centre" to align your text to the centre of each column. In order to confine it to the same width of the image, I would suggest playing around with setting a CSS "padding" on the column divs like so (excuse the inline styling):

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-4" style="padding: 0px 50px">
  <img class="center-block" src="images/newveh.png" alt="Generic placeholder image" width="280" height="175">
  <h3 style="text-align: centre"><b>New Vehicles</b></h3>
  <p style="text-align: centre">Jr Audi has the latest Audi models available.</p>
  <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button">&raquo; View New Inventory</a></p>
</div><!-- /.col-lg-4 -->
```

Comment: Since you are using bootstrap, just a reminder for you to check how this works as a responsive solution.